# Discord.py buttons - Adding role to member returns NoneType error

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a button using the discord-components package with the discord.py module.

I have the following code:

```py
@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(
        "This is a button test",
        components = [
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Button 1")
        ]
    )


    res = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    if res.channel == ctx.channel:
        member = await res.guild.get_member(res.user.id)
        await member.add_role(853692936465940501)
        await res.respond(
            type=InteractionType.ChannelMessageWithSource,
            content=f"{res.component.label} has been clicked! This is button 1"
        )
```

But I seem to have issues, getting a error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: object NoneType can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Why does the guild.get_member return a NoneType?
Does anybody maybe have some example code of how to implement role changing using discord.py buttons? Because I cannot seem to get this to work

Thanks :)

Comment: `get_member` is a normal function, not a coroutine.  You do not need to `await` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do that firstly, make sure you imported Discord as well.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

And then you can simply get the user using this:
`user = client.get_user(INT)`

Comment: @itzFlubby You can look again on what he said, the guild.member is returning NoneType , and that is an alternative solution.

Comment: He's asking **why** "guild.get_member return[s] a NoneType?". I don't see an answer to that in your post but nvm

Comment: @itzFlubby That is why I said to enable the intents firstly! And then if it doesn't work, try to replace guild.get_member by client.get_user. That is it!

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(
        "This is a button test",
        components = [
            Button(style=ButtonStyle.blue, label="Button 1")
        ]
    )


    res = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    if res.channel == ctx.channel:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id = 853692936465940501)
        await res.author.add_roles(role)
        await res.respond(
            type=4,
            content=f"{res.component.label} has been clicked! This is button 1"
        )
```